# Auto iconv of Doctrine query

Tags: php, doctrine, iconv

How do I set up Doctrine to automatically run iconv() when building a query and fetching data?

Comment: Which version of Doctrine you are using? 2.x or 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hope nobody ever has to face charset conversion problems in their lives and all charsets except UTF8 will soon be a thing of the past. Anyway, just to give some feedback to my own question. I solved by writing a custom hydrator that extends Record hydrator and by overriding some symfony prcessValues methods of Filter base classes like this:

```
abstract class BaseFormFilterDoctrine extends sfFormFilterDoctrine
{
  public function setup()
  {
  }
  public function processValues($values)
  {
    $values = parent::processValues($values);
    $charset = strtolower(str_replace('-','',$this->getTable()->getConnection()->getCharset()));
    if ($charset != 'utf8')
    {
      foreach ($values as $key => $value)
      {
        if (isset($value['text']))
        {
          $values[$key]['text'] = iconv('utf8', $charset, $value['text']);
        }
      }    
    }

    return $values;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just tell the RDBMS you're using to send the data in UTF-8? `Doctrine_Connection` has a `setCharset` method for this:

```
$connection->setCharset('utf8');
```

Comment: It is fine with Mysql, for example. Doing so, doctrine will add a SET NAMES query. But some RDBMSs don't support SET NAMES (MSSQL, for example). So, once again, what is the best \ easiest way to proccess query data in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

`setCollation()` is the corresponding one.